# Need assistance with ReadFile method in java....?

Tags: java, swing

I'm stuck with this question and was hoping to get help here. I just need to know how to get started because that's what I'm stuck on.

Here's the question:

Assume file employees.txt exists and has the following format:
name    id number    gross pay
Write method readFile.  readFile accepts an id number, searches file, employees.txt, for the employee with that id number, and returns their gross pay.

Comment: What u have tried so far ? Add some code snippet to get better solution.

Comment: You will have to show what you have done trying yourself. The question itself looks like homework and that we can't/ ain't going to do for you.

Comment: `I just need to know how to get started` - start one step at a time. First learn how to read a file one line at a time and then use System.out.println(...) to display each line of data. Then move on to the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you can see the basic steps.

1.First create a File object like this:

`File myfile = new File("path of the particular file");`

2.Create FileReader object and give the created myfile object as a parameter.

`FileReader fr = new FileReader(myfile);`

3.Make buffered reader object.

`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);`

4.now you can read the file line by line and put it into a string as like below.

`String str = br.ReadLine();
System.out.println(str);`